# Word wheel for JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

[Word Wheel](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/word+wheel)

For lack of better known terms I noted when going through some [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) in Swing that JLists have a built in word wheel look up feature. I select anywhere in my list and start typing to navigate towards the items I want. Three questions to this:

1. Is there a more appropriate term within the community for this style of searching?
2. Looking through the [JList API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) it wasn't apparent to me what resulted in this functionality. Any direction as to where to look would be appreciated, is it a function of what the constructor takes? I do not feel it is part of [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) as JTables are components and do not seem to display this functionality; which leads me to....
3. Can this functionality be applied as *easily* to JTables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a more appropriate term within the community for this style of searching?

Autocomplete might be another term for what you're looking for.

> Looking through the JList API it wasn't apparent to me what resulted in this functionality. Any direction as to where to look would be appreciated, is it a function of what the constructor takes? I do not feel it is part of Component as JTables are components and do not seem to display this functionality; which leads me to....

The functionality is provided by the [`JList#getNextMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getNextMatch(java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.Position.Bias)) method, which is called by the UI delegate in response to a key event

> Can this functionality be applied as *easily* to JTables?

Well, that's a subjective question and is based on your concept of *easily*

The problem is, it could actually interfere with the current default functionality of the `JTable`, which allows you to start editing a cell on a key event, so it might not be desirable.

`JTable` is a much more complex component, do you want to limit searching to a single column or include multiple columns?  Do you want to use `Object#toString` (like `JList`) or provide a more flexible filtering mechanism?

You could take a look at [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a ready made alternative, but this might not meet your requirements.

Instead, I would provide a "search" field, which would allow the user to type their search query in.  With a little work, you could make this search the table automatically and highlight the matches as the user types, but that's just me...

Comment: How is .getNextMatch exactly being called automatically? I hadn't called it directly.

Comment: It's called by the UI (look and feel) delegate in response to a `KeyEvent` from a registered `KeyListener` in the delegate

Comment: Defiantly a rabbit trail this one. I'll see what I can do to trace this out. Thank you MadProgrammer

Comment: For what's it's worth, the issue I have with the `JList` implementation is that it uses `Object#toString` of the data object and does not provide a means to modify this without extending the `JList` itself.  This means that when the data is rendered differently, the mechanism breaks down

Comment: @TargetofGravity you can to override getNextMatch in JList, that allows you various filtering, note have to test if Object is instance of String :) and to test if bias == Position.Bias.Forward, e.g. then you can highlight all matches in Renderer, but with JTable (one column, without JTableHeader) is life easier,

Comment: @MadProgrammer then is possible to override getNextMatch in JComboBox as TableCellEditor, but by using, filtering of events from KeyListener (ENTER is ignored, filtered, used for editor)